# In QGIS, create series of contours represented by polygons that is generated by a buffer with assigned elevation

Tags: qgis

When I'm using the Model Designer, "Geometry by Expression" is great to generate geometry. Coupling that with an expression that generate an array you can generate multiple geometries during one execution of Geometry by Expression. However, I want to set a field, (or z value). How do you do that? Is there another algorithm besides Geometry by Expression that I need to use, so that I can set a field on a feature vs just have the multiple geometries that need to be collected together into one feature with collect_geometries?

(I'm sure this is better done with python, but my python is weak and I'm hoping to stick with just expressions.) But if someone has a python solution, I'd take that as well.

[image: screen shot of Geometry by expression]

Comment: Don't understand what you want to do. You mean Field Calculator...?

Comment: "Geometry by Expression" as the name suggest use an expression to return a Geometry, if you need to add a field and/or to calculate a field you may use "Add field to attributes table", "Refactor fields", "Field calculator", ... . In any case the model designer is made to let you chain several processing tool but without more detail on your end goal and starting data it's hard to help.

Comment: Remember to provide code as text (optionally image as well, but text is important if you're looking for people to help you)!